# How do I set "visible" CPU and memory for a container?

Tags: linux, container

I wrote a simple container in C as described in [this article](https://blog.lizzie.io/linux-containers-in-500-loc.html) (not affiliated) and it works well. The container has mount, UTS, IPC, PID and cgroup namespace separated (via clone(2)).

There's one thing I haven't figured out: I want to limit the "visible CPU and memory" for the container, as shown by `htop` and similar utilities. My current implementation moves the child (PID 1 of the new PID namespace) into a new cgroup as shown in the following pseudo-code:

```bsh
pid_t pid = fork();
# Child goes other stuff
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/example
echo $pid > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/example/cgroup.procs
echo 1073741824 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/example/memory.limit_in_bytes  # 1 GiB
```

Now when the child attempts to allocate more than 1 GiB of memory, it gets killed, which is the expected behavior. However, utilities like `htop` still shows the full amount of memory on the host (e.g. 4 GB).

Similarly, I can put the child in a new CPU subcgroup and constrain its CPU usage, but `htop` shows the total amount of CPU (and their loads) of the host.

How should I limit the "visible" amount of memory and affinity of CPU for a container? It seems like both Docker and LXC do this very well.

Comment: From what I read, docker doesn't limit visible CPUs. It does limit CPU usage.